# How to Handle Complex Edge Cases of Webscraping using bs4?

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

> Please Take a loot at this HTML structure :

```
<span style="text-decoration: underline; color: #0000ff;"><a style="color: #0000ff; text-decoration: underline;" href="https://www.biharjobportal.com/muzaffarpur-indian-army-rally-recruitment-online-form/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Muzaffarpur Indian Army Rally Recruitment 2020 <span style="color: #ff0000; text-decoration: underline;">Last Date – 14.01.2021</span></a></span>
```

> Inside the Span Tags there is the `href` link and the `Text` as well
> Here is a screenshot of the website , just in case :

[image]

> the highlighted one is creating all the Issues

> I managed to get all my required data (text and links). **To get all the Links, I wrote this code** :

```
    r = requests.get('https://www.biharjobportal.com/', headers = headers )
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml'
    first_column =soup.find('div', {'class': 'elementor-column elementor-col-33 elementor-top-column elementor-element elementor-element-b892ae7'}) 
    link = first_column.find_all('a', {'style': 'color: #0000ff; text-decoration: underline;'})
    for i in link:
      links = i['href']
      print(len(links))
```

> And to get all **the Names inside the links**, I wrote this code :

```
title = first_column.find_all('span', {'style': 'text-decoration: underline; color: #0000ff;'})
for item in title:
    MainTitle = item.text
    print(len(MainTitle))
```

> I later realized that **`Only One of the Items`** (as shown in the Pic) doesn't follow the Stricture of other links. This is the Strucuture, the one single link has :

```
<a href="https://www.biharjobportal.com/nsp-pre-and-post-matric-scholarship-online-form/" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><span style="text-decoration: underline; color: #0000ff;">NSP Pre and Post Matric Scholarship Form 2020 <span style="text-decoration: underline; color: #ff0000;">Last Date 30.12.2020</span></span></a>
```

> As You can see , Its quite opposite Structure. `Here, the span Tag in inside of href tag` , which excludes itself/not included while scraping the links, Thus completely deteriorating the data Mining from this Website.

> Now The `len(title) = 36` and `len(link) = 35` , which are not accepted by Pandas Dataframe as well (as it gives the Length should be same error everytime)

> What should I do in this Case ? I know many Experienced devs are here. Please Guide me . Thanks

Comment: Looks like all the links are within `<li>` elements somewhere all contained within one div, and are the only child node of the `<span>` element within which they exist. Can't you just iterate over all of them outputting the child node and make this easier (and instead of relying on styles that could change) ?

Comment: i did that already ,but there's element which has two link's inside it. So, thats the Issue

Comment: pls check the Image again, I highlighted the one

Comment: @Sainita : Please accept the answer if this resolved to your query. Instead of saying thanks please make sure you have accepted and voted for the answer that will encourage SO contributors. Please note that On SO you can accept only one answer at time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the links are within `<li>` tags, try searching for an `<li>` tag followed by an `<a>` tag. (The length is 42).

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36"
}

r = requests.get("https://www.biharjobportal.com/", headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
first_column = soup.find(
    "div",
    {
        "class": "elementor-column elementor-col-33 elementor-top-column elementor-element elementor-element-b892ae7"
    },
)
title = first_column.find_all("li")

for tag in title:
    print(tag.find("a")["href"])
```

Output:

```
https://www.biharjobportal.com/muzaffarpur-indian-army-rally-recruitment-online-form/
https://www.biharjobportal.com/lnmu-pg-admission-online-form/
https://www.biharjobportal.com/ssc-chsl-recruitment-online-form/
https://www.biharjobportal.com/bihar-board-12th-exam-date-sheet/
https://www.biharjobportal.com/bpsc-project-manager-recruitment/
https://www.biharjobportal.com/munger-university-ug-admission-online-form/
https://www.biharjobportal.com/biscomaun-various-post-recruitment/
https://www.biharjobportal.com/bihar-police-constable-bharti/
https://www.biharjobportal.com/bseb-crossword/

...
...
```

Comment: Thanks For the answer, Will definitely try

Answer (score 1):

You could remove all spans using red color and extract the text afterwards:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {
    'User-agent':
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36'
}

r = requests.get('https://www.biharjobportal.com/', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

allColumns = soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'elementor-widget-wrap'})
for column in allColumns:
    _headerObj = column.find('h2')
    if _headerObj and 'latest update' in _headerObj.text.lower():
        _allLinks = column.find('ul')

        for link in _allLinks.findAll('a'):
            # find all spans and remove the one using red color!
            _spans = link.findAll('span')

            for span in _spans:
                if '#ff0000' in span['style']:
                    span.extract()

            _text = link.text
            print(link['href'])
            print(_text)
            print("")
```

Out:

```
https://www.biharjobportal.com/muzaffarpur-indian-army-rally-recruitment-online-form/
Muzaffarpur Indian Army Rally Recruitment 2020

https://www.biharjobportal.com/lnmu-pg-admission-online-form/
LNMU PG Admission 1st Selection List 2020

https://www.biharjobportal.com/ssc-chsl-recruitment-online-form/
SSC CHSL Recruitment Online Form 2020

https://www.biharjobportal.com/bihar-board-12th-exam-date-sheet/
Bihar Board Inter Exam Date Sheet 2021

https://www.biharjobportal.com/bpsc-project-manager-recruitment/
BPSC Project Manager Recruitment 2020

https://www.biharjobportal.com/munger-university-ug-admission-online-form/
Munger University UG Spot Admission 2020

https://www.biharjobportal.com/biscomaun-various-post-recruitment/
BISCOMAUN Various Post Admit Card

https://www.biharjobportal.com/bihar-police-constable-bharti/
Bihar Police Constable Bharti 2020

https://www.biharjobportal.com/bseb-crossword/
BSEB Crossword Competition 2020-21

https://www.biharjobportal.com/bssc-anuwadak-recruitment-online-form/
BSSC Anuwadak New Exam Date 2020 Released

https://www.biharjobportal.com/ekalyan-bihar-scholarship/
Ekalyan Bihar 10th पास बालक/बालिका स्कॉलरशिप 2020

https://www.biharjobportal.com/nsp-pre-and-post-matric-scholarship-online-form/
NSP Pre and Post Matric Scholarship Form 2020

https://www.biharjobportal.com/bpsc-66th-combined-exam-online-form/
BPSC 66th Combined Vacancy Increased & Rejected List

https://www.biharjobportal.com/jawahar-navodaya-vidyalaya-6th-class-online-admission-form/
JNV 6th Class Admission Form 2021

https://www.biharjobportal.com/jnv-class-9th-admission-online-form/
JNV Class 9th Admission Online Form 2021

https://www.biharjobportal.com/lnmu-integrated-b-ed-cet-online-form/
LNMU B.Ed Document Verification Call Letter 2020

https://www.biharjobportal.com/jai-prakash-university-graduation-admission-online-form/
JPU UG Admission 1st Allotment List 2020

https://www.biharjobportal.com/bssc-inter-level-exam-online-form/
BSSC Inter(10+2) Level Mains Exam 2020

https://www.biharjobportal.com/csbc-bihar-police-driver-constable-recruitment/
CSBC Bihar Police Driver Constable Admit Card 2020

https://www.biharjobportal.com/bihar-rajya-fasal-sahayta-yojana/
बिहार राज्य फसल सहायता योजना 2020 –

https://www.biharjobportal.com/bihar-bseb-ofss-inter-admission-online-form/
BSEB OFSS Inter Admission 2020

https://www.biharjobportal.com/brabu-graduation-admission-online-form/
BRABU UG Admission 2020

https://www.biharjobportal.com/bsusc-assistant-professor-recruitment/
BSUSC Assistant Professor Recruitment 2020

https://www.biharjobportal.com/simultala-awasiya-vidyalaya-admit-card/
Simultala Awasiya Vidyalaya Admit Card 2020

https://www.biharjobportal.com/indian-air-force-cat-online-form/
Indian Air Force CAT Online Form 2020

https://www.biharjobportal.com/lnmu-ug-admission-online-form/
LNMU UG Admission Re-Open 2020

https://www.biharjobportal.com/bihar-bcece-board-city-manager-bharti/
Bihar BCECE Board City Manager Admit Card 2020

https://www.biharjobportal.com/bihar-iti-admission-online-form/
Bihar ITI Admit Card 2020

https://www.biharjobportal.com/bihar-polytechnic-dcece-online-form/
Bihar Polytechnic DCECE Admit Card 2020

https://www.biharjobportal.com/lnmu-pg-admission-online-form/
LNMU PG Admission Online Form 2020 –

https://www.biharjobportal.com/bceceb-amin-recruitment/
BCECEB Amin Recruitment 2020

https://www.biharjobportal.com/bihar-csbc-forest-guard-recruitment/
Bihar CSBC Forest Guard Admit Card 2020

https://www.biharjobportal.com/bihar-bseb-deled-exam-date-sheet/
Bihar BSEB D.El.Ed Exam Date 2020

https://www.biharjobportal.com/bihar-bseb-deled-exam-date-sheet/
Latest News

https://www.biharjobportal.com/magadh-university-graduation-admission-online-form/
Magadh University UG Spot Admission

https://www.biharjobportal.com/veer-kunwar-singh-university-ug-admission-online-form/
VKSU UG Spot Admission 2020

https://www.biharjobportal.com/bihar-rajya-swasthaya-samiti-anm-bharti-online-form/
Bihar SHSB (Advt No-03/2020) ANM Admit Card 2020

http://biharjobportal.com/bihar-scert-ntse-scholarship-exam/
Bihar SCERT NTSE Scholarship Exam 2021

https://www.biharjobportal.com/bihar-scert-nmmss-scholarship-examination/
Bihar SCERT NMMSS Scholarship Examination 2021 –

https://www.biharjobportal.com/bihar-police-home-guard-recruitment/
Bihar Police Sepoy (Sipahi) New Exam Date Notice

https://www.biharjobportal.com/ssc-delhi-police-constable-recruitment/
SSC Constable in Delhi Police Admit Card 2020

https://www.biharjobportal.com/bpsc-acf-recruitment-online-form/
BPSC ACF Recruitment Exam Date 2020

https://www.biharjobportal.com/csbc-bihar-police-constable-recruitment/
CSBC Bihar Police Constable New PET Exam Date
```

Comment: Thanks For the answer, Will definitely try